# Whats better for perfomance animationFrame or onScroll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requestanimationframe

I have a marquee element I have create with react.  I want the marquee to stop when the element is not visible.

Here is my code for checking visibility:

```
const isVisible = () => {
  const rect = marqueeRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
  const elTop = rect.top;
  const elBottom = rect.bottom;
  const visible = elTop < wHeight && elBottom >= 0;
  return visible;
};
```

I am wondering what would be better for performance:

a. Let the animation frame run and check each time if the element is visible.

```
const animate = () => {
  if (isVisible()) {
    i = i < width ? i + step : 0;
    marqueeRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${-i}px)`;
  }
  aF = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
```

or

b. Make an onScroll handler to check if the element is visible and then start and stop the animation frame.

```
const onScroll = () => {
  if(isVisible()){
    animate();
  }else{
    cancelAnimationFrame(aF);
  }
}
```

Both ways would constantly check to see if the element is visible so I was wondering if anyone had any experience with this and could shed some light on which would be better performance wise.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that scroll event is called only in painting frames, so it's better than a requestAnimationFrame loop here. But the accepted answer is right, for your case IntersectionObserver is even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Intersection observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) is perfect for this. It has better performance than either of those options because it only calls your callback when the element becomes either visible or not visible (depending on a given threshold), and has a relatively simple API to boot.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't even aware this was available and it seems to have pretty good browser support as well.